# Loading Umlaute from MySql-Db

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core

I have a strange Problem.

I use Asp.Net Core 2.0.5 .
And i load Data from a MySql-Database with the NuGet MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.11 .

When i try load Data from the Database with

```
protected readonly DbContext _context;
protected readonly DbSet<Mandant> _dbSet;    

 public Task<Mandant> GetMandantNoTrackAsync(int id)
   {
            return this._dbSet.Where(m => m.MandantID == id).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync();
   }
```

Where Mandant is

```
public class Mandant
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("MandantID")]
        public int MandantID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        [Column("MandantName")]
        [Display(Name = "Mandantname")]
        public string MandantName { get; set; }
    }
```

then it replaces Umlaute with strange symbols. e.g. TestMändätTest turns to TestM�nd�tTest. 
Not only on the Page itself, but directly the Data I load from the Database.

But when i save TestMändätTest with the following function into the Database, it is correctly saved there.

```
public async Task UpdateMandantAsync(int ID, string Name)
        {
            var item = await _dbSet.FindAsync(ID);
            item.MandantName = Name;
            _dbSet.Update(item);
        }
```

If it helps DB-Connection-String:

```
server=192.168.2.230;userid=tester;pwd=test;port=3306;database=Mandanten;sslmode=none;CharSet=utf8;
```

How can i Load the Text correctly from the Database?

Comment: What does the server create the table as `SHOW CREATE TABLE Mandant` as a SQL statement, what does it show? Edit the question.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `Mandant` (
  `MandantID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MandantName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MandantID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UQ_Mandant_Name` (`MandantName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: work out how to add a `utf8mb4` character set to the entire table or the MandantName.